# use spacy parse tree to extract key-value pairs

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am working on a project to extract details from medical reports. I am new to NLP and all its libraries. I have been using spaCy so far and found that the Parse tree that spaCy returns is very good but I dont know how to make use of it.

[image]

For example "The heart and lungs are functioning normally"
I want the output as-

```
{"heart:"functioning normally","lungs":"functioning normally"}
```

Another example "The basilar artery shows normal flow"
output - `{"basilar artery":"normal flow"}`

Can someone give an example of how to these extract details or which tools to use(regular expression, phrase matching, etc). 
Should I use some completely different approach to get the desired output or is spaCy the best way to go?